# Open and Click tracking event webhook not firing after the email is opened in Sendgrid

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I have a requirement of tracking "open" and "click" events of Sendgrid. I have enabled 'Open' and 'Click' tracking in tracking setting in my Sendgrid account. I have enabled required events in Event webhook under Mail settings-->Event Settings.

[image: Web Hook settings]

When I send the email,I get the event webhook response for "unsubscribed" events, but if I open the emails I do not get any webhook response. I tried opening the email in Yahoo, outlook and in Gmail. However, the event of open and click are never fired to our configured URL. I can see the open and click emails on the Sendgrid statistics page, but I don't get the webhook event of those.

What may be wrong here?

I tried to explain my problem. I am expecting people to provide the solution to my problem by giving me some hints on the missing part.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom, there is a "Test Integration" button. When you click that, does your API receive sample data from Sendgrid?

Also, under "Tracking" in the left menu, there is "Open Tracking" and "Click Tracking" settings. I don't recall if this is required whenever you have the checkbox for opened/clicked checked in your Event Webhook, but you might want to try enabling these tracking items if you are not getting the open/clicks.